# Proving that the $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \infty$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n + 1}{a_n} = k > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am working on a proof as follows:

Let $k > 1$ and $(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ be a sequence where $a_n > 0$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = k$$

Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = +\infty$

I have ascertained that when n is large enough, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 1$ and that $a_{n+1} > a_n$ so $(a_n)$ will be strictly monotone increasing.

However, this is not strong enough to show the sequence tends to infinity.

I feel like I understand the notion of why it tends to infinity, the strict inequality meaning it won't converge however I'm not sure how to prove it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show that $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geqslant \sqrt{k}$ for all large enough $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Herein, we present a standard approach that relies on the definition of the limit.  To that end we proceed.

---

If $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=k>1$, then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a number $N(\epsilon)$ such that whenever $n>N(\epsilon)$,

$$k-\epsilon<\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<k+\epsilon$$

Take $\epsilon=\frac{k-1}{2}$.  Then, for $n>N\left(\frac{k-1}{2}\right)$, we see that

$$a_{n+1}>\left(\frac12+\frac k2\right)a_n$$

where $\left(\frac12+\frac k2\right)>1$.

Proceeding recursively, we find that

$$a_{n+m}>\left(\frac12+\frac k2\right)^ma_n$$

Letting $m\to \infty$, we obtain the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\infty$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 2):

Choose an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $1+\epsilon < k$. We know that there exists an $N$ such that
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1+\epsilon$$
for all $n\ge N$. Thus we have that $a_{n+1}>(1+\epsilon)a_n$. Then applying this recursively we have that
$$a_{N+k}>(1+\epsilon)^ka_N$$
And we see that $a_N>0$ and $(1+\epsilon)^k\to\infty$ so $a_{N+k}\to\infty$.

Comment: Will, I understand.  I would encourage you to be more precise on the choice of $\epsilon$ here.  See my post for details.  ;-)) -Mark

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

there exists $a>1$ and $N\geq 0$  s.t

for $n\geq N$,

$$\frac{u_n}{u_{n-1}}\geq a$$
$$\frac{u_{n-1}}{u_{n-2}}\geq a$$

.

.

$$\frac{u_{N+1}}{u_N}\geq a$$

use telescoping and geometric sequence.

Answer (score 0):

lim{a_(n+1)}=lim {a_(n+1)/a_n}*{a_n}=lim{a_(n+1)/a_n}*lim{a_n}. This only works if lim a_n is infinity.